# dynamically pass unknown number of parameters to react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my react App, I have the functionality to create Folders and Files. A folder can have any number of folders inside it.

like so

```
Folder-1
  |_Folder-1-1
  |_Folder-1-2
    |_Folder-1-2-1
    |_Folder-1-2-2
      |_Folder-1-2-2-1
       .
       .
       .
```

and it can get deeper up to any level.
Currently, What I am doing is. There's a component that loads the root folder `Folder-1`, When you click on `Folder-1`. I change the route and load another component.

My route Looks like `<Route exact path="/clients/:folder" component={ClientFolder} />`

But the problem here is I don't know the number of parameters.

The way I envisioned it is

- You click on `Folder-1`, URL changes to `/clients/Folder-1`,
  Then, it loads all the Folders inside Folder-1, i.e `Folder-1-1`, and `Folder1-2`
- You click on `Folder-1-2`, URL changes to `/clients/Folder-1/Folder-1-2`, Loads Files and folders inside `Folder-1-2`

and so on.

So my question is, **How can I have Any number of nested routes using a single route and a single Component**

I am using react-router 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the exact match it would work

You can refer to this sample https://codesandbox.io/s/great-tu-yr85t

Comment: How can I get those values in my component?

Comment: Updated the Sandbox code you can check . You can get the path using the **props.match.url**

Comment: if url is `/team/45/34` then `props.match.url` only returns `/team/45` but I want to get 34 to render the component data. so considered the `location.pathname` and split it into an array `/` then directly targetted the last element using `arr[arr.length-1]`

Comment: Hi @SandeepRanga Thanks for contributing to stack overflow! Would you mind including the code of your answer in the question itself (with a bit of explanation if possible)? I ask you to do this because it is a stack overflow policy to do so. Since there may be licensing issues arising when including code from a third party website. Also this makes for a better and more complete answer!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using the match all `*`. Something like:

```
<Route path="/clients/*">
```

Whatever path is passed after `/clients` will then be available in `match.params["0"]`.